# Displaying non processing QGIS plugin icon in processing toolbox

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I am developing a QGIS processing plugin that has many algorithms. Apart from various processing algorithms, there is one tool that is non-processing. I would like to display them all together to the user.

Is it possible in QGIS to put a non-processing tool icon in the processing toolbox?

Once a user clicks the icon it will act as any other non-processing tool.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-processing tool"?

Comment: Non-processing plugin or a simple python script that is not a processing script.